# Capturing url from email click to be used after the user logs in

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an MVC asp.net web application using bootstrap and angularjs that requires the user to log in.  On occasion, we will send the user an email with links to detail info on the site.  When we click the link in the email, it sends the user to login, but then does not go to the detail.

Link in email http://mywebapp.com/filedetail#!/filedetail/1234

I was going to use the Request.RawUrl, but for some reason, it only contains: http://mywebapp.com/filedetail
If I use http://mywebapp.com/filedetail/filedetail/1234, rawurl has the data, but then trying to use the link if the user is already logged in, the web page contains no formatting.  It appears the the "#!" is not compatible with the request data.

Not sure how to solve this.

Any help would be appreciated...